# Set background image according to screen resolution

Tags: image, background, screen, resolution

I would like to be able to change my webpage background image according to the screen resolution the user uses so:

if screen resolution is greater than or equal to 1200*600 then background = mybackground.jpg no-repeat or else. How can I do this?

Comment: or else what?  did you mean: 'or else background = myalternatebackground.jpg no-repeat'

Comment: media queries in css3

Answer (score 23):

Pure CSS approaches that work very well are discussed [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). Two techniques are examined in particular and I personally prefer the second as it not CSS3 dependent, which suits my own needs better.

If most/all of your traffic has a CSS3 capable browser, the first method is quicker and cleaner to implement (copy/pasted by Mr. Zoidberg in another answer here for convenience, though I'd visit [the source](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) for further background on why it works).

An alternative method to CSS is to use the JavaScript library jQuery to detect resolution changes and adjust the image size accordingly. [This article](http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/quick-tip-resizing-images-based-on-browser-window-size/) covers the jQuery technique and provides a live demo.

[Supersized](https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized) is a dedicated JavaScript library designed for static full screen images as well as full sized slideshows.

A good tip for full-screen images is to scale them with a correct ratio beforehand. I normally aim for a size of 1500x1000 when using supersized.js or 1680x1050 for other methods, setting the jpg quality for photographs to between 60-80% resulting in a file size in the region of 100kb or less if possible without compromising quality too much.

Answer (score 16):

**Delete your "body background image code" then paste this code:**

```
html { 
    background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed #000; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi heres a javascript version which changes the background image src according to screen resolution. You have to have the different images saved in the right size.

```
<html>
<head>    
<title>Javascript Change Div Background Image</title>        
<style type="text/css">    
body {
         margin:0;
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
}

#div1 {   
    background-image:url('sky.jpg');
    width:100%
    height:100%
}    

p {    
    font-family:Verdana;    
    font-weight:bold;    
    font-size:11px;    
}    
</style>    

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changeDivImage()    
{   
//change the image path to a string   
var imgPath = new String();        
imgPath = document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage;  

//get screen res of customer
var custHeight=screen.height;
var custWidth=screen.width;

//if their screen width is less than or equal to 640 then use the 640 pic url
if (custWidth <= 640)
    {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(640x480.jpg)";
    }

else if (custWidth <= 800)
    {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(800x600.jpg)";
    }

else if (custWidth <= 1024)
    {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(1024x768.jpg)";
    }

else if (custWidth <= 1280)
    {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(1280x960.jpg)";
    }

else if (custWidth <= 1600)
    {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(1600x1200.jpg)";
    }

else {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(graffiti.jpg)";
     }

    /*if(imgPath == "url(sky.jpg)" || imgPath == "")        
    {            
    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(graffiti.jpg)";        
     }
    else        
     {            
     document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(sky.jpg)";        
     }*/
}    

</script>
</head>
<body onload="changeDivImage()">            

<div id="div1">   

 <p>This Javascript Example will change the background image of<br />HTML Div Tag onload using javascript screen resolution.</p>    
 <p>paragraph</p>
</div>    

<br/>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too old question but thought to answer, it might will help someone. If you see twitter, you will find something very tricky but pure css approach to achieve this.

```
<div class="background"><img src="home-bg.png" /></div>
Applied CSS
.background {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    height: 200%;
    left: -50%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200%;}

.background img{
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;}
```

This background images fits to all size. even portrait view of ipad. it always adjust the image in center. if you zoom out; image will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Set body css to :

```
body { 
background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed #000; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue but have now found the resolution for it.

The trick is to create a wallpaper image of 1920*1200. 
When you then apply this wallpaper to the different machines, Windows 7 automatically resizes for best fit.

Hope this helps you all

Answer (score 0):

Put into css file:

```
html { background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; }
```

URL *images/bg.jpg* is your background image