# Rails 4 image is larger in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, haml

I have a background image that scales during development (running localhost). In production though, the image doesn't scale (shrink) with the screen.

[image: screenshot] 
[image: iphone]

```
.content
  overflow: hidden
  max-width: 100%
  max-height: auto
  background-image: image-url("project.jpg")
  background-attachment: fixed
  background-size: cover
  background-position: top center
```

I'm wondering if its a heroku issue, or my code is messed up.

Comment: background-repeat:no-repeat;

   background-size:cover;
max-width: auto

Comment: `max-width: auto;` is invalid - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

Comment: The Chrome device emulator shows something different from using the actual device. Can you provide a trimmed down demo of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Changes may be required as per you vie code according to class/id you are using with elements.

**HTML**

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}

#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

If your problem still not rectified please see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12795523/5239247)

Comment: I'm afraid this solution didn't work for me. but thanks for trying.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it's including an image in the markup, so it's impossible to work with it for responsive via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark: Why don't you try `background-size: contain;`?

Using `background-size: contain;` will show the whole image and it will resize it accordingly to fit the width and/or height of its parent container maintaining its aspect ratio as well.